# HTML5 cache downloads root every time

Tags: html, offline-caching, cache-manifest

I am playing with HTML5 app cache and right from the beginning I ran into issues:/
I am trying to have simple offline fallback for my page so that there would be nice styled page instead of classic offline error. According to few resources I have red I created this manifest file.

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 0.01
CACHE:

NETWORK:
*

FALLBACK:
/ /offline.html
```

The problem is, that the browser loads into the cache not only the `offline.html` file, but also the root page, which leads into that page is displayed with lot of errors (no js loaded, no imaged loaded, no CSS, ...) while offline and `offline.html` is completely bypassed by the browser.
The screenshot below shows logged information about caching progress. You can see there, that the browser downloads both files, instead of only the `offline.html` as I am trying to do.

All this has been done in latest dev Chrome (23.0.1262.0 dev)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page which references the manifest file is always included in the offline cache.  If you don't want the root page to be cached then you need to create a separate static page to reference the manifest and load it in an `iframe`.