# HTML5 Application Cache only for dependencies

Tags: html, browser-cache

I want to cache only a few files like JavaScript and CSS, font files and image sprites.

Is it better to add a manifest file for the files or should I let the browser do the cache?

If it's better with manifest, can I still leave the pages inaccessible if a user has no network connection? How?

I don't want this website to work offline, I just want a faster page load on secondary pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the page you use to reference the manifest file will itself always be cached.  See:

- [HTML5 cache downloads root everytime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12419652/8655)
- [HTML5 cache manifest no cache for html file itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5045782/8655)

So you will always have at least one page which is available offline.  However this can be a page which is otherwise not normally accessed, and you can reference it in an `iframe` from your online pages.

Comment: Hm... I frame, sound interesting :) Thanks a lot!